# ACF custom date field not matching in wp query

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently using custom post types as hotel reservations / bookings. The post type includes several custom fields but the one I am struggling with is the date field for check in check out dates.

I am using wp_query to retrieve bookings that match a room name and check in date, I can match them and get bookings by room name but I can never match on the date. I have tried several different date formats and tried many different approaches but nothing seems to be work.

The strange thing is if I retrieve the custom post's just by room name and then perform a match in php like this (if($fullyear === get_field('check_in'))) it returns true so the dates match. Below is my WP query, any help would be much appreciated, I've been going round in circles for days with this one.

```
                $bookingposts = new WP_Query(array(
                    'numberposts'   => 20,
                    'post_type'     => 'bookings',
                    'meta_query'    => array(
                    'relation'      => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'key'       => 'check_in',
                            'type'      => 'DATE',
                            'value'     => $fullyear,
                            'compare'   => '='
                            ),
                        array(
                            'key'       => 'room_number',
                            'value'     => $roomnumber,
                            'compare'   => '=',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ));
```

I'm working with date format 'd/m/y' and ACF is returning in that format.

Comment: Did you use date_query instead of meta query for date operations in wordpress.

Comment: I don't think I can use date_query because I am relying on custom date fields.

Comment: Looks like my problem was that when filtering with wordpress dates in custom fields you need to use yyyy-mm-dd format!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my problem was that when filtering with wordpress dates in custom fields you need to use yyyy-mm-dd format! So once ACF was returning that format everything worked like a charm.